# For median is it optimal to compare in pairs first?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, lower-bounds, time-complexity, sorting

Median can be done in linear time and is now down to (I think) $2.97n$.
The lower bounds is (I think) $(2+\epsilon)n$ where $\epsilon$ is very small.

The following theorem, if true, may help improve lower bounds in general and
upper bounds for particular small values of $n$:

> If MEDIAN of $n$ elements can be found
>   in $f(n)$ comparisons (worst case)
>   then there is an algorithm taking
>   $f(n)$ (perhaps $f(n) + O(1)$) that
>   initially compares all of the elements
>   in pairs.

One can also look at other selection problems, element distinctness, sorting,
and other such problems.

(Meta Question - I couldn't find a good tag for this so I used lower-bounds.
Is there a better one that I missed?)

Comment: Could you describe this a bit better? We can't do every pairwise comparison, obviously, because that's quadratic time.

Comment: @Eli - Maybe GASARCH means the definition from "On lower bounds for selecting the median" (http://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=10317167134453583556), that is: ". . . algorithm that starts by comparing \floor{n/2} disjoint pairs of elements . . ."

Comment: @jbapple That link to Google Scholar doesn't work anymore. I tried entering by typing in, searching a bit on key words, no luck. Could you provide source info, or update the link maybe? Thanks

Comment: @Feral Oink - It was just a link to the Google Scholar search for the paper "On lower bounds for selecting the median". http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.31.1412

Comment: @jbapple Oh! Okay! Thank you. That is so much more familiar to me, CiteSeerX and of course DOI. Much appreciated. I clicked, all was well.